# Why would IIS return some Blazor WebAssembly dlls but return 403 Forbidden for others?

Tags: blazor, iis-7.5, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly project targeting .net6 and published to a server running IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008.  When I go to the site url with the dev tools open I can see that some of the dll files are loaded successfully but others returned a 403 Forbidden.  One odd thing about it is that it is not the same dlls getting the 403 each time.  I can refresh the browser and some that got 403 the first time will load and others that loaded the first time get 403.  I tried changing all the dll files to .bin files like suggested here (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5477#issuecomment-599148931) but I get the same results.

Here is the first pageload:
[image]

and here is after refreshing the page in the browser:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was caused by the Dynamic IP Restrictions setting in IIS.  It was set to 5.  I increased the restriction and all the dll files loaded.

[image]

I found this thanks to this question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4977d000-baac-42b9-80c7-20f06cc0e5d3/iis-random-forbidden-403-static-files-on-browser-refresh

Answer (score 1):

In my case, on a Plesk panel, the problem was under "Web Application Firewall". I just disabled it and the dll's have started being downloaded.